# Update 2d String array with method that takes in two 2d string arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have to take in a 2d array and multiple each row of it by the other corresponding 2d array.

Here are the files:

```
Omaha,104,1218,418,216,438,618,274,234,510,538,740,540
Saint Louis,72,1006,392,686,626,670,204,286,236,344,394,930
Des Moines,116,1226,476,330,444,464,366,230,602,260,518,692
Chicago,408,948,80,472,626,290,372,282,488,456,376,580
Kansas City,308,1210,450,234,616,414,500,330,486,214,638,586
Austin,500,812,226,470,388,488,512,254,210,388,738,686
Houston,454,1086,430,616,356,534,218,420,494,382,476,846
New Orleans,304,1278,352,598,288,228,532,418,314,496,616,882
```

File Two:

```
Omaha,7.5
Saint Louis,10.5
Des Moines,8.5
Chicago,11.5
Kansas City,12.5
Austin,10.75
Houston,12.5
New Orleans,9.25
```

Example:  When I compare `array[0][0]` to `price[0][0]` the strings match therefore I must take the whole ROW of `array[0]` and multiply each element by that of `price[0][1]` to update the array.

Now here is my code:

```
public static String [][] updateString(String[][] array, String[][] prices)
    {
        String [][] newArray = new String[array.length][]; 
        for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
        {
            if (array[row][0].equals(prices[row][0]))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
                {
                    Double d=Double.parseDouble(array[row][i+1]) * Double.parseDouble(prices[row][1]);
                    newArray[row][i+1] = d.toString();
                } 
            }

        }

        return newArray;
    }
```

Here are my errors I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at assign_1.DansUtilities.updateString(DansUtilities.java:430)
at assign_1.SalesReportGenerator.main(SalesReportGenerator.java:50)
```

**line 430 is my method. line 50 is where I call it.

new code:

public static String [][] updateString(String[][] array, String[][] prices)
        {

```
        for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
        {
            if (array[row][0].equals(prices[row][0]))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i<array[row].length; i++)
                {
                   {Double d=Double.parseDouble(array[row][i]) * Double.parseDouble(prices[row][1]);
                    array[row][i] = d.toString();}
                } 
            }

        }

        return array;
```

heres my new errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Omaha"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at assign_1.DansUtilities.updateString(DansUtilities.java:429)
at assign_1.SalesReportGenerator.main(SalesReportGenerator.java:50)
```

Comment: Your code is crying for objects. Each row seems to be a city (string), followed by N prices (integers or doubles). You should model that as an object, and not as a String array. Especially since you're using numbers which should have a nueric type and not be of type String.Java is an OO language. Define your own classes and use them.

Comment: Is this an assignment that requires you to use those wacky arrays?  Arrays are an awful way to do this.  If they are not specifically required, follow JB Nizet's advice and become aware to objects.

Comment: This is an assignment that requires me to use these arrays :(

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException can only be thrown if your array is null. Check in the code that is calling the method.

Other notes to improve your code:

1. you do not need a new array to store values. You can do it in existing array itself.
2. your inner for loop must be from 1 to the length of current row not the length of the array so it should be something like:

   for(int i=1;i<array[row].length;i++) 
   And use index i instead of i+1 in loop content.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create output of your strings, to see whether they are correctly read from files.

```
    private static void outputString2D(String[][] s, String name) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < s[i].length; j++ ) {
                System.out.println(name + " contains at [" + i + "][" + j + "]:\t" + s[i][j]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Example how I used it:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[][] str = new String[2][3];

    str[0][0] = new String("I am 0,0.");
    str[0][1] = new String("I am 0,1.");
    str[0][2] = new String("I am 0,2.");
    str[1][0] = new String("I am 1,0.");
    str[1][1] = new String("I am 1,1.");
    str[1][2] = new String("I am 1,2.");

    outputString2D(str, "str");
}
```

Example output:

```
str contains at [0][0]: I am 0,0.
str contains at [0][1]: I am 0,1.
str contains at [0][2]: I am 0,2.
str contains at [1][0]: I am 1,0.
str contains at [1][1]: I am 1,1.
str contains at [1][2]: I am 1,2.
```

Provide us the content of your two strings please.